# RATreeView Row Select Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Since upgrading to swift 3 I have not been able to get the row select to work for RATreeView. Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I have not been able to get it to work"? Providing a replicable representation with code would also be helpful.

Comment: In swift 2 didSelectRowForItem was getting called but after upgrading to swift 3 it wasn't anymore. However after upgrading the version of the ratreeview it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your version of ratreeview is the latest and that your ios platform is correct in your podfile.